# My 'for' loops are not running in JavaScript (using Node.js to run a JavaScript file)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider:

```js
let data = [{
    a: 93,
    b: 23,
    c: 56
  },
  {
    a: 96,
    b: 14,
    c: 45
  },
  {
    a: 83,
    b: 5,
    c: 65
  },
  {
    a: 99,
    b: 16,
    c: 47
  },
  {
    a: 78,
    b: 31,
    c: 59
  },
]

let isdata = {
  a: 50,
  b: 34,
  c: 32
}

let prop_names = Object.keys(data[1])
console.log(prop_names)
let answers = []

for (let q = 0; q > prop_names.length; q++) {
  console.log(answers)
  for (let i = 0; i > data.length; i++) {
    answers[q] += data[i].propnames[q]
  }
}

for (let x = 0; x > answers.length; x++) {
  answers[x] /= data.length
}

console.log(answers)
```

As you can from the code snippet, when I console.log answers inside the `for` loop it doesn't run, but when outside the `for` loop it does. This code is supposed to loop through each property of each object and average the values.

Comment: What is the intended and the actual output? Why did you include parts that are not relevant to the question?

Comment: `q > prop_names.length`  So you are saying: `0 > 3`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Peter_Mortensen This is an old question and to be honest I can hardly read it myself. I think I was trying to ask why my for loop wasn’t running and my problem was that I had the greater than and less than sign mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code that you have shared:

1. The loop conditions are incorrect. You have used `>` whereas it should be `<`.
2. You have not initialized the `answers` array, but you are using `+=` to add `current value` with `previous value`.
3. You are accessing `data` array incorrectly. The correct syntax will be `data[i][props_names[q]]`. Take a look at [the bracket notation to access an object property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

A working solution is as follows:

```js
var data = [{
    a: 93,
    b: 23,
    c: 56
  },
  {
    a: 96,
    b: 14,
    c: 45
  },
  {
    a: 83,
    b: 5,
    c: 65
  },
  {
    a: 99,
    b: 16,
    c: 47
  },
  {
    a: 78,
    b: 31,
    c: 59
  },
]

var isdata = {
  a: 50,
  b: 34,
  c: 32
}

var prop_names = Object.keys(data[1])
console.log(prop_names)
var answers = Array.from(prop_names, () => 0);

for (var q = 0; q < prop_names.length; q++) {

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    answers[q] += data[i][prop_names[q]]
  }
}

for (var x = 0; x < answers.length; x++) {
  answers[x] /= data.length
}

console.log(answers)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [javascript w3 docs](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) explains the second statement in a for loop:

`Statement 2 defines the condition for executing the code block.`

So you for loop => `for(let q = 0; q > prop_names.length; q++)` indicates you want `q` to start at 0, and run the inner code when `q` is larger that `prop_names.length`, then increment, which will never happen. Change all your second statements in for loops to run the inner code when `q` is smaller than length of array such as this -

`for(let q = 0; q < prop_names.length; q++)`

Also, change `data[i].propnames[q]` to `data[i][prop_names[q]]` since `data[i]` does not have `propnames` as a key.

Comment: problems were fixed

Answer (score 0):

First you mixed up `<` and `>` in all if statements.
Secondly, you need to use something like `data[i][prop_names[q]]` instead of `data[i].propnames[q]`
Here is working example:

```js
let data = [
  {
  a: 93,
  b: 23,
  c: 56
 }, 
  {
  a: 96,
  b: 14,
  c: 45
 },
  {
  a: 83,
  b: 5,
  c: 65
  },
  {
  a: 99,
  b: 16,
  c: 47
  },
  {
  a: 78,
  b: 31,
  c: 59
  }
]

let prop_names = Object.keys(data[1])
console.log('prop_names:', prop_names)
let answers = []

for(let q = 0; q < prop_names.length; q++) {
  answers[q]=0
 for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  answers[q] += data[i][prop_names[q]]
 }
}

for(let x = 0; x < answers.length;x++) {
 answers[x] /= data.length
}


console.log('answers:', answers)
```